# Interpretation of narrow-sense heritability over one (using R/S = h^2)

Tags: genetics, evolution, population-genetics, selection

Here is my data:

Mean height score of the total parental population: 5.2

Mean height score of selected parents (those chosen for breeding due to their higher height): 6.4

Mean height score of the offspring (resulting from the selected parents): 7.8

Selection differential (S) for height:
S = Mean height score of selected parents - Mean height score of the total parental population
S = 6.4 - 5.2 = 1.2

Response to selection (R):
R = 7.8 - 5.2 = 2.6

h^2 = R / S

h^2 = 2.6 / 1.2 = 2.167

I confirmed that the data are not wrong. What is the interpretation of this h^2 value?

I am looking for explanations for why h^2 would be above one.

Answer (score 1):

Check your assumptions.

It looks like you're using a formula that assumes linear, additive variance. Your data suggest a system that does not follow these assumptions, so the equations are not valid for the situation you describe.

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong - much of the difficulty in applying simple mathematical formulae to real world data is in deciding/recognizing when your model is sufficiently wrong that it's no longer useful.

Comment: What could explain that? Dominance? I thought of that, but I assumed that would decrease h^2, not increase it

Comment: @BigMistake I would start by assuming the trait is simply nonlinear. No reason that things have to be linear in the real world just because it's sometimes convenient to model.

Comment: Another possibility would be non-independence of the environment. If there's a systematic environment change that's going to affect population parameters outside of the heritability.

Comment: Actually, I think dominance could elevate h^2 above 1. The regressed slope would be above 1

Comment: I know these things can bias h^2 estimates, but I'm specifically wondering about what can result in them being above one, not just generally inaccurate

Comment: Both reasons I suggested could have this result. It's not that surprising: when assumptions are violated an equation is no longer valid.

Comment: How would they increase h^2?

Comment: They don't, they make the equation you are using to calculate it invalid.

Comment: Exactly. I am looking for why h^2 is calculated to be too high, not why the equation is invalid

Comment: Because you're using an invalid equation to calculate it because the assumptions that make the equation hold are not met - that's why it's too high. R is a bigger response than is possible under the model that makes that equation hold.

Comment: Assumptions not being met ≠ reason why a particular direction of bias is observed. Assumptions being met = reasons why it is wrong, but ≠ reasons why it is wrong in a specific direction.

Comment: R is large. That's it. In another situation with violated assumptions it could be small instead. The direction isn't important what is important is that it's not meaningful. If you tried to calculate how much money you have in the bank by multiplying what you deposit by what you spend you get the wrong answer because that equation is wrong. It's not important to explain why the result is too big or too small, it's just not meaningful to use that equation in that situation.